# removing Arabic Diacritic using Python

Tags: python, arabic

I want to filter my text by removing Arabic Diacritic using Python

for example

Text :  اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا
after filltring : اللهم اغفر لنا ولوالدينا

I have found that this can be done using CAMeL Tools but I am not sure how

Comment: Looks like this answer has what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/518232/11946287

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for Arabic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the library [pyArabic](https://pypi.org/project/PyArabic/) like this:

```
import pyarabic.araby as araby

before_filter="اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا"
after_filter = araby.strip_diacritics(before_filter)

print(after_filter)
# will print : اللهم اغفر لنا ولوالدينا
```

You can try different strip filters:

```
araby.strip_harakat(before_filter)  # 'اللّهمّ اغفر لنا ولوالدينا'
araby.strip_lastharaka(before_filter)  # 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا'
araby.strip_shadda(before_filter)  # 'اللَهمَ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا'
araby.strip_small(before_filter)  # 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا'
araby.strip_tashkeel(before_filter)  # 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا'
araby.strip_tatweel(before_filter)  # 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا'
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
text = 'text with Arabic Diacritics to be removed'    
text = ''.join([t for t in text if t not in ['ِ', 'ُ', 'ٓ', 'ٰ', 'ْ', 'ٌ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ّ', 'َ']])
print(text)
```

if you want the full list of Arabic Diacritics you can also get it from pyArabic, standalone example:

```
import unicodedata
try:
    unichr
except NameError:
    unichr = chr

text = 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا '    
text = ''.join([t for t in text if t not in [unichr(x) for x in range(0x0600, 0x06ff) if unicodedata.category(unichr(x)) == "Mn"]])
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use any library for this, just plain regex:

```
import re
text = 'اللَّهمَّ اغْفِرْ لنَا ولوالدِينَا '    
output=re.sub(u'[\u064e\u064f\u0650\u0651\u0652\u064c\u064b\u064d\u0640\ufc62]','',text)
print(output)
#اللهم اغفر لنا ولوالدينا
```